# Replace every quotation in a file by an escaping quotation with java

Tags: java, file, replace, escaping, edit

I am trying to edit a file with java.

I would like to escape every Quotation " in my file with \"

I tried it like this (regards to the other solution on stackoverflow, which code I could copy):

```
public void replaceInFile(File file) throws IOException {

File tempFile = new File("twittergeoUpdate.csv");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

Reader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

while (br.ready()) {
fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("\"", "\\\"") + "\n");
}

fw.close();
br.close();
fr.close();
}
```

I was too fast... It doesn't work for me. The Quotation just stay untouched in my file. Any ideas ?

Comment: You can't write to a file and not expect it to change when you read it. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\\"` only escapes `"`(double quote), you have to escape the back-slashes aswell, thus you need 5 backslashes. `\\\\\"`

```
s.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava()` from Apache `commons-lang` package.

Like this:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(<yourStringLiteralHere>)
```

**From javadoc**:

`StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava()` escapes the characters in a String using `Java` String rules.

Deals correctly with quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.)

So a tab becomes the characters '\' and 't'.

The only difference between `Java` strings and `JavaScript` strings is that in `JavaScript`, a single quote must be escaped.

**Example**:

- input string: He didn't say, "Stop!"
- output string: He didn't say, \"Stop!\"

Answer (score 1):

I coded:

```
public void replaceInFile(File file) throws IOException {

    File tempFile = new File("twittergeoUpdate.csv");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

    Reader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while (br.ready()) {

        fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"") + "\n");
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();
}//replaceInFile
```

The correct replacement string is \\\" (5 backslash, not 3)

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that you cannot write to a file you are reading from and not expect it to change. In your case, the first thing FileWriter does is *truncate* the file.  I have seen examples where the reader still manages to read something but it is corrupted.

You have to write to a temporary file, close both files and when finished replace (using delete and rename) your original file with the temporary one.